# How do I create a velocity template that outputs two '#' litterals at the beginning of the line?

Tags: java, velocity

I need to create a velocity document that has some lines prefixed with ¨## Foo", but since the `#` is the velocity directive command, it is not working for me.

What I want my **output** document to look like:

```
## Foo this
## Bar that
k1, v1
k2, v2
k3, v3
```

Escaping has not worked out how I expected.  The below does not work, obviously, as the `#`s are un-escaped):

```
## Foo this
## Bar that
#foreach( $foo in $bar )
$foo.key, $foo.value
#end
```

The ## lines don't show up--again, as expected.  But, my attempts at escaping do not work either.  Escaping solution one:

```
\## Foo this
\## Bar that
#foreach( $foo in $bar )
$foo.key, $foo.value
#end
```

or this, escaping solution two:

```
\#\# Foo this
\#\# Bar that
#foreach( $foo in $bar )
$foo.key, $foo.value
#end
```

or even this...

```
# set($msg = "##") 
$msg Foo this
$msg Bar that
#foreach( $foo in $bar )
$foo.key, $foo.value
#end
```

This last one really confused me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sigh....There is a difference between single quote and double quotes.  This works as expected:

```
#set($msg = '##') 
$msg Foo this
```

Which prints out exactly what I wanted:

```
## Foo this
```

From the [Velocity Users Guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html):

> Single quotes will ensure that the quoted value will be assigned to the reference as is. Double quotes allow you to use velocity references and directives to interpolate, such as "Hello $name"

*(I'm still stumped as to why \#\# does not work.)*

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Velocity context](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/EscapeTool.html):

```
${esc.h}${esc.h}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to add [org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.EscapeTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/EscapeTool.html) or similar to your context, you can use a slightly modified version of your third try:

```
#set($msg = "#") 
${msg}${msg} Foo this
```

Comment: This works, and doesn't require messing with the context (which would require a code changes on my part.)  Fantastic.  I don't understand why "##" doesn't work, but this 2x "#" does.  :P  But, I'm not complaining...it works!

Comment: I assume that when Velocity parses the template, comments are extracted before anything else. So everything after the double hash in the template would disappear entirely. But I'm just guessing.

Answer (score -1):

"##" is the single line comment delimiter in VTL, which is probably the start of your problems.

```
## This is a comment
```

Comment: Obviously, and why I state as much in the question.